# Git push - does not appear to be a git repository (ssh pointing to wrong directory)

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, openssh

### The case:

I have installed the project [omnibus-gitlab](https://www.gitlab.com/gitlab-ce/) in an ubuntu release 12.04 following [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md) tutorial.

Everything seems to be correct. The server is working normally through the lan by the IP *192.168.1.68* and I can access all the features of gitlab (with the browser).

There I created a project with the **root** user (administrator) named as **project1** *(also the keys are properly configured)*

With the project created through the browser, I created it again in my local workspace, defining it as a repository (made some changes) committed and pushed it to the server. Basically I followed these steps:

```
mkdir teste
cd teste
git init
touch README
git add README
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin git@192.168.1.68:root/project1.git
git push -u origin master
```

At the moment of the **push** command, the terminal returned this message:

```
root@pcname:~Projects/project1# git push -u origin master
git@192.168.1.68's password:
fatal: 'root/project1.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Ok. Making some attempts to discover why this was happening, I just realized that when we access the ssh server `git@192.168.1.68` we are not accessing the truly repository directory, instead of this, we are accessing 3 previous levels.

So, this is the directory which has the repositories:

`/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories` and here we have the `root/project1.git` directory/repository.

Instead of that path, when we access `git@192.168.1.68:root` We are actually accessing:

`/var/opt/gitlab` which does't have the `root` directory.

Therefore the result is naturally the git warning that no repository has been found.

*ps: whether instead of `git@192.168.1.68:root/project1.git` we use `git@192.168.1.68:git-data/repositories/root/project1.git` it works very well and we are able to push the repository normally.*

### The question:

Why is this happening and how can I direct the ssh address to the correct directory (or repository) path?

Comment: If `root` redirects to `/var/opt/gitlab` can you not use `git remote add origin git@192.168.1.68:root/git-data/repositories/project1.git`?

Comment: No, because `git@192.168.1.68:root/git-data/repositories/project1.git` would be accessing the path `/var/opt/gitlab/root/git-data/repositories/project1.git`. The correct path is `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/root/project1.git`, so I can use the command `git@192.168.1.68:git-data/repositories/root/project1.git` *but that does not seems the correct way*

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the absolute path of directory you want when adding the origin to push to:

```
git remote add origin git@192.168.1.68:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/root/project1.git
```

Alternately, to answer your question about directing the ssh to the repository directory (or some other path) then you need to create a user with that path as the home dir and use that in your origin connection. Assuming you make the home dir of ***newuser*** the ***repositories*** directory you'd use:

```
git remote add newuser@192.168.1.68:root/project1.git
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have been running into the same issue.

You probably need to configure your keys correctly. Your /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys should look like (containing your key of course):

```
command="/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell key-2",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB..your.key...... someoneskey@keylabs.lab
```

(!) please note that some of the documentation seems to be outdated and the paths have changed

if you ssh to your node

```
ssh -T git@mynode.com
```

it should say:

```
Welcome to GitLab, <yourname>!
```

and the connection should be closed. If it says

```
Welcome to GitLab, Anonymous!
```

Your user is not recognised. You need to add your key to your user within the web interface.

If you are able to log in with the git user via ssh, your authorized_keys are not configured as mentioned above

**Edit:**
To be clear, it seems like you don't need any additional authorized_keys when setting up gitlab. My authorized_keys file is empty and gitlab works as it should.